# How to animate a glass pane with its Form?

Tags: codenameone

When a `Form` is displayed and the `show`method of another `Form` is invoked the new `Form` animates over the old one.

However the glass pane apparently doesn't participate in the animation which looks odd.

Is there a way to make the glass pane participate in the animation?

Here is some code:

```
    Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
    hi.add(new Label("Hi World"));
    hi.setGlassPane(new Painter() {
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics aGraphics, Rectangle aRectangle) {
            int width = hi.getWidth();
            int height = hi.getHeight();
            int size = Math.min(width, height) * 2 / 3;
            aGraphics.setColor(0xff0000);
            aGraphics.fillRoundRect((width - size) / 2, (height - size) / 2, size, size, size / 4, size / 4);
        }
    });
    hi.getToolbar().addCommandToRightBar(new Command("Other") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent aActionEvent) {
            Form form = new Form("Other Form");
            form.getToolbar().addCommandToLeftBar(new Command("Back") {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent aActionEvent) {
                    hi.showBack();
                }
            });
            form.setGlassPane(new Painter() {
                @Override
                public void paint(Graphics aGraphics, Rectangle aRectangle) {
                    int width = hi.getWidth();
                    int height = hi.getHeight();
                    int size = Math.min(width, height) * 2 / 3;
                    aGraphics.setColor(0x2020ff);
                    aGraphics.fillRoundRect((width - size) / 2, (height - size) / 2, size, size, size / 4, size / 4);
                }
            });
            form.show();
        }
    });
    hi.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported in the current implementation of `CommonTransitions` it might be possible to add a special case to that class that will detect glass pane and paint it on top.

Comment: It's not like the glass pane would not be shown, it just does not take part in the animation. Obviously the glass pane is painted in a different graphics context. I'd consider it an error because the Form is rendered with an offset while the animation is ongoing but the glass pane is not, right?

Comment: Glass pane is a special case, so much so that even the screenshot feature of the simulator doesn't grab it.